# 2D zoom to point in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, gl-matrix, regl

I'm trying to create a 2D graph visualization using WebGL (regl, to be more specific). With my current implementation I can already see the force layout being applied to each node, which is good. The problem comes when I try to zoom with respect to the current mouse position. According to my research, to achieve this behavior, it is necessary to apply matrix transformations in the following order:

```
translate(nodePosition, mousePosition)
scale(scaleFactor)
translate(nodePosition, -mousePosition)
```

So, every time the `wheel` event is fired, the mouse position is recalculated and the transform matrix is updated with the new mouse position information.
The current behavior is weird and I can't seem to understand what is wrong. [Here  is a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/922pkr64jw?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js).

[image]

Apparently, if I zoom in and out with the mouse fixed at the initial position, everything works just fine. However, if I move the mouse and try to focus on another node, then it fails.

The function for retrieving the mouse position is:

```
const getMousePosition = (event) => {
    var canvas = event.currentTarget
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top
    var projection = mat3.create()
    var pos = vec2.fromValues(x,y)
    // this converts the mouse coordinates from 
    // pixel space to WebGL clipspace
    mat3.projection(projection, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight)
    vec2.transformMat3(pos, pos, projection)
    return(pos)
}
```

The `wheel` event listener callback:

```
var zoomFactor = 1.0
var mouse = vec2.fromValues(0.0, 0.0)
options.canvas.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    mouse = getMousePosition(event)
    var direction = event.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1
    zoomFactor = 1 + direction * 0.1
    updateTransform()
})
```

And the function that updates the transform:

```
var transform = mat3.create()
function updateTransform() {
    var negativeMouse = vec2.create()
    vec2.negate(negativeMouse, mouse)
    mat3.translate(transform, transform, mouse)
    mat3.scale(transform, transform, [zoomFactor, zoomFactor])
    mat3.translate(transform, transform, negativeMouse)
}
```

This `transform` matrix is made available as an uniform in the vertex shader:

```
  precision highp float;
  attribute vec2 position;

  uniform mat3 transform;

  uniform float stageWidth;
  uniform float stageHeight;

  vec2 normalizeCoords(vec2 position) {
    float x = (position[0]+ (stageWidth  / 2.0));
    float y = (position[1]+ (stageHeight / 2.0));

    return vec2(
        2.0 * ((x / stageWidth ) - 0.5),
      -(2.0 * ((y / stageHeight) - 0.5))
    );
  }

  void main () {
    gl_PointSize = 7.0;
    vec3 final = transform * vec3(normalizeCoords(position), 1);
    gl_Position = vec4(final.xy, 0, 1);
  }
```

where, `position` is the attribute holding the node position.

#### What I've tried, so far:

- I already tried changing the order of the transformations. The result is even weirder.
- When I apply either translation or scaling independently, everything looks ok.

This is my first interaction with something that is not the usual SVG/canvas stuff. The solution is probably obvious, but I really don't know where to look anymore. What am I doing wrong?

### Update 06/11/2018

I followed @Johan's suggestions and implemented it on the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/922pkr64jw?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js). Although the explanation was rather convincing, the result is not quite what I was expecting. The idea of inverting the transform to get the mouse position in the model space makes sense to me, but my intuition (which is probably wrong) says that applying the transform directly on the screen space should also work. Why can't I project both the nodes and the mouse in the screen space and apply the transform directly there?

### Update 07/11/2018

After struggling a little, I decided to take a different approach and adapt the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437153/5288378) for my use case. Although things are working as expected for the zoom (with the addition of panning as well), I still believe there are solutions that do not depend on d3-zoom at all. Maybe isolating the view matrix and controlling it independently to achieve the expected behavior, as suggested in the comments. To see my current solution, check my answer bellow.

Comment: Your transformation maps the model to the target view-port.  If you want to correct for a translation due to scaling (say delta), which is a distance in target coordinates, you need to transform this delta in model coordinates.  That is, determine the inverse of your transformation and calculate with that the correction in model coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, @Johan. I will try this in a few hours to see what happens!

Comment: If it was me I'd separate the view/camera matrix from everything else. I'd store the camera as a position and a zoom level and compute a view matrix from that every frame.

Comment: I thought camera matrices were only used when dealing with 3D spaces, but I'm probably wrong. Given my limited experience with webgl, that's probably the way to go. Thanks for the suggestion, @gman!

Comment: Whether you want to call it camera or not I just mean something that controls a view matrix that gets applied at the top. The code below then just works in *world* coordinates and you've separated how it gets viewed. Whether or not it's the right thing to do I don't know :P  Effectively a 2D display can be thought of a 3D display with an orthographic camera so like an orthographic display in a 3D modeling package you can slide and zoom the camera for different views of the scene. Even if you only use 3x3 matrices for a 2D display you'll get the same effect by separating out the view part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after failing with the original approach, I managed to make [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437153/5288378) work for my use case.

The `updateTransform` function is now:

```
var transform = mat3.create();
function updateTransform(x, y, scale) {
    mat3.projection(transform, options.canvas.width, options.canvas.height);
    mat3.translate(transform, transform, [x,y]);
    mat3.scale(transform, transform, [scale,scale]);
    mat3.translate(transform, transform, [
      options.canvas.width / 2,
      options.canvas.height / 2
    ]);
    mat3.scale(transform, transform, [
      options.canvas.width / 2,
      options.canvas.height / 2
    ]);
    mat3.scale(transform, transform, [1, -1]);
}
```

And is called by d3-zoom:

```
import { zoom as d3Zoom } from "d3-zoom";
import { select } from "d3-selection";

var zoom = d3Zoom();

d3Event = () => require("d3-selection").event;

select(options.canvas)
      .call(zoom.on("zoom", () => {
          var t = d3Event().transform
          updateTransform(t.x, t.y, t.k)
       }));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2wzn3v1yz) is the live demonstration with this solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your transformation maps the model to the target view-port. If you want to correct for a translation due to scaling (say delta), which is a distance in target coordinates, you need to transform this delta in model coordinates. That is, determine the inverse of your transformation and calculate with that the correction in model coordinates

Simple example preparing the transformation for scaling around a center in view-port coordinates is given below:

```
function map (a, p) {
    return [a[0] * p[0] + a[3] * p[1] + a[6],a[1] * p[0] + a[4] * p[1] + a[7]];
}

function scale(transform,scale,viewCenter1) {    
    var inverted = mat3.create();
    mat3.invert(inverted,transform);
    var modelCenter1 = map(inverted,viewCenter1);   // scale from this point in model

    mat3.scale(transform,transform,[scale,scale]);
    var viewCenter2 = map(transform,modelCenter1);  // map model center to screen 
    var viewShift = [viewCenter1[0]-viewCenter2[0],viewCenter1[1]-viewCenter2[1]];

    mat3.invert(inverted,transform);
    var modelShift = map(inverted,viewShift) - map(inverted,[0,0]);
    mat3.translate(transform,[-modelShift[0],-modelShift[1]]);   // correct for the shift
}

// pass the transformation to webgl environment
```

Comment: Alright, so I plugged your code in the live demo to see what happens. After fixing some lines, the result is not what I expected, although your explanation seems rather convincing to me. I'll update the answer and the demo with your proposal. What exactly is this `map` function doing? Why can't I apply the transforms directly on the viewport space?

Comment: The map function returns a transformed point. Input the transformation and the point to transform, output the transformed point. I had a fast look at the mat3 library you are using and did not find such a function.

Comment: Please mind the typo (aarghhhh) in the map function. The last term is a[7] and not a[6]. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: I had a look at the example. It flies away. I need some time to have a look at that in say 6 hours.

Comment: That's okay! So is this `map` function different from a vector-matrix multiplication, where the vector is the point on the form of (x,y,1) and the matrix (3x3) is the transformation? I'll update my question with a solution I adapted from another answer using d3-zoom, though I would appreciate if we could find the solution just using this matrices transformations.

Comment: So is this map function different from a vector-matrix multiplication: no it is the same.